# Gremlin query to get a vertex with its child vertices, even if it doesn't have any children

Tags: gremlin

Let's say I have [this graph](https://gremlify.com/wxmq1udx9v8) (link to Gremlify):

[image: Graph with three nodes, two of which have a relationship]

I need a query to get a vertex with all its child vertices (up to a certain depth). We already have one that seems to work:

```
g.V("4840")
 .repeat(outE().inV().simplePath())
 .times(5)
 .emit()
 .path()
 .by(valueMap(true))
```

The result is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 4840,
      "label": "Vertex"
    },
    {
      "id": 4842,
      "label": "child"
    },
    {
      "id": 4838,
      "label": "Vertex"
    }
  ]
]
```

So I now have the vertex with the edge and the child vertex. Great. But what if I use id 4836? Then I get an empty array. This is because this vertex doesn't have any outgoing edges. Is there a way to construct a query that will give me a vertex with its linked vertices, but also the vertex itself if it doesn't have any edges?

You can play around with this [here](https://gremlify.com/wxmq1udx9v8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to switch the `repeat()` from `while..do` to `do..while` by moving the `emit()` to the front of the `repeat()`:

```
g.V("4840")
 .emit()
 .repeat(outE().inV().simplePath())
 .times(5)
 .path()
 .by(elementMap())
```

Comment: Gives a slightly different result structure-wise, but this is what I was looking for indeed.

Comment: there was no particular reason why i switched to `elementMap() ` except that it produces a better representation than `valueMap(true)`. You typically only need `valueMap()` if you are using multi-properties.